# How to generate element in xsd file as jaxb classes

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd, wsdl

I need help to figure out how to generate  type as class.

This is the xsd file I have.

```
<xsd:element name="GetPatient" type="c:GetPatientType" />
<xsd:complexType name="GetPatientType">
   <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="fieldA" type="xsd:string" />
   <xsd:element name="fieldB" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

However, the result is
- I got GetPatientType with the fields, but there is no GetPatient class. My goal is to generate GetPatient with all the three fields as its field. So, GetPatient with field A and field B. Is that possible?

Thanks all for your help!

Comment: https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/xjc.html

Comment: how do you generate your classes? jaxb2-maven-plugin or other solution

Answer (score 1):

See this question:

> [wrapper class missing when using xjc on xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549171/wrapper-class-missing-when-using-xjc-on-xsd)

You don't get a class for `GetPatient` because JAXB handles it via the `JAXBElement<GetPatientType>` construct.

You can, however, customize `GetPatient` to generate a class via the `<jaxb:class name="GetPatient"/>` customization. But still, that class will not have the fields, it will be just a wrapper class.

See also:

> [How to generate @XmlRootElement Classes for Base Types in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514110/how-to-generate-xmlrootelement-classes-for-base-types-in-xsd)